# Reshaping data: Extract "some" rows and turn them into a new column in R

Tags: r, reshape

(EDITED) I have a very long dataset with multiple columns in long format. Here's an example of the data:

```
Groups duration response  value      trial
------ -----    -------- --------- --------
C       525      ID       5578        ID
C       525      1-1      676|342     C3
C       525      1-2      676|342     C3
C       525      1-3      676|342     C3
C       525      1-4      676|342     C3
C       525      1-5      676|342     C3
C       521      ID       6331        ID
C       521      1-1      643|461     C3
```

In this data frame, the ID of each participant is in the same column as the responses and values. What I need is to get the rows that correspond to the "ID" into a separate repeated-measures column so that it looks something like this:

```
Groups duration  ID     response   value      trial
------ -----   ------   --------  --------- --------
C       525     5578       1-1      676|342    C3 
C       525     5578       1-2      676|342    C3
C       525     5578       1-3      676|342    C3
C       525     5578       1-4      676|342    C3
C       525     5578       1-5      676|342    C3
C       525     5578       1-6      676|342    C3
C       521     6331       1-1      643|461    C3
C       521     6331       1-2      643|461    C3
C       521     6331       1-3      643|461    C3
C       521     6331       1-4      643|461    C3
C       521     6331       1-5      643|461    C3
C       521     6331       1-6      643|461    C3
```

My original attempt was to turn the data frame into a wide format so that the ID and the other responses each had their own column, then make it long again but only for columns 1-1 to 1-6 in the example, with this code:

```
df <- spread(df, response, value)

#fill in the whole column with corresponding values
df<-fill(df, ID, .direction="down")

df <- gather(df, name, coordinates, 9:1417, factor_key=TRUE)
```

The first part works. I get a data frame with an ID column. However, when I try to turn the other columns back into a long format, I get an error: "Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)"

I think this is because there are too many columns and my memory just can't take it.
Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An option is to create a grouping based on the occurrence of 'ID' by doing the cumulative sum of logical vector (`response == 'ID'`), then create the 'ID' column as the `first` element in 'value', then remove the first row with `slice` and remove the 'grp' column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(response == 'ID'), Groups) %>%
   mutate(ID = first(value)) %>%
   slice(-1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  Groups duration response value   trial ID   
#  <chr>     <int> <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>
#1 C           525 1-1      676|342 C3    5578 
#2 C           525 1-2      676|342 C3    5578 
#3 C           525 1-3      676|342 C3    5578 
#4 C           525 1-4      676|342 C3    5578 
#5 C           525 1-5      676|342 C3    5578 
#6 C           521 1-1      643|461 C3    6331
```

---

If we need to expand the rows by having 'response' from '1-1' to '1-6'

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(response == 'ID'), Groups) %>%
    mutate(ID = first(value)) %>%
    slice(-1) %>%
    group_by(Groups, duration, value, trial, ID, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    complete(response = str_c('1-', 1:6)) %>% 
    ungroup  %>%
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 6
#   Groups duration value   trial ID    response
#   <chr>     <int> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>   
# 1 C           525 676|342 C3    5578  1-1     
# 2 C           525 676|342 C3    5578  1-2     
# 3 C           525 676|342 C3    5578  1-3     
# 4 C           525 676|342 C3    5578  1-4     
# 5 C           525 676|342 C3    5578  1-5     
# 6 C           525 676|342 C3    5578  1-6     
# 7 C           521 643|461 C3    6331  1-1     
# 8 C           521 643|461 C3    6331  1-2     
# 9 C           521 643|461 C3    6331  1-3     
#10 C           521 643|461 C3    6331  1-4     
#11 C           521 643|461 C3    6331  1-5     
#12 C           521 643|461 C3    6331  1-6
```

The advantage is that we don't need to do any reshaping, instead it is creating the column on the same data and remove some rows at the end

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Groups = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C"), duration = c(525L, 525L, 525L, 525L, 525L, 525L, 521L, 
521L), response = c("ID", "1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "1-4", "1-5", 
"ID", "1-1"), value = c("5578", "676|342", "676|342", "676|342", 
"676|342", "676|342", "6331", "643|461"), trial = c("ID", "C3", 
"C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "ID", "C3")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: I like this approach!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column (`ID`) with `value` and `replace` it with `NA` for `response != 'ID'`, `fill` the `NA` values and remove rows with `response = 'ID'`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ID  = replace(value, response != 'ID', NA)) %>%
  fill(ID) %>%
  filter(response != 'ID')

#  Groups duration response   value trial   ID
#1      C      525      1-1 676|342    C3 5578
#2      C      525      1-2 676|342    C3 5578
#3      C      525      1-3 676|342    C3 5578
#4      C      525      1-4 676|342    C3 5578
#5      C      525      1-5 676|342    C3 5578
#6      C      521      1-1 643|461    C3 6331
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach could be to split on the cumsum and then recombine (and re-order the columns to get the expected output):

```r
df <- split(df, cumsum(df$response =="ID"))
do.call(rbind, lapply(df, function(x) {
    y=x[-1,]; y$ID <- x$value[1]; y[, c(1:2,6,3:5)]}))
```